# Creating a loop for serial monitor output

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Small description for you... Using arduino uno I am trying to make it so I press a button to switch on the entire program, not hold down press but press and let it release to make it on then do it again to make it off. While its on it needs to output data given from a LDR every 1 second.

Anyway, in the serial monitor (output of data) I want it to say "off" to start with then say "on" after the button is pressed. I have gotten this far.

My problem is when it is on, i cant figure out how to make it display the LDR light sense amount each second while also testing that if it goes over 500 for example, it should then stop and say alarm triggered. And be able to be switched off after also.

Here is my code:

```
   // Devices attached
const int  buttonPin = 2;    // Pin that BUTTON uses
const int sensorPin = 0;       // Pin that SENSOR uses

// List of dynamic variables
int pushCounter = 0;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int lastbuttonState = 0;     // previous state of the button

void setup() 
{
  // Set the BUTTON as an INPUT
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  // Create serial prompt
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  // read the pushbutton current state
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastbuttonState) 
  {

    // if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonState == HIGH) 
    {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button
      // wend from off to on:
      pushCounter++;

      int sensorValue = 0;
  // Divides counter by 2, if remainder (not0), then the following
 if (pushCounter % 2 == 0){
     analogWrite(sensorPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Power ON");
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
    delay(1000);
 }
else
  {
    analogWrite(sensorPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("OFF");
  }

    // Debouncing delay
    delay(250);
  }

  // Save the current BUTTON state as the LAST state
  lastbuttonState = buttonState;

  }
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hgnXKueS

Comment: after a small update http://pastebin.com/jnz4zjeC

Comment: Why are you using digital pins for analog input? use A0 instead.

Comment: And refrain from using serial pins D0 and D1 for normal input output ops. It can give you uncertain results

Comment: Okay i'll bare that in mind thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be a question of task multithreading. It is not possible in bare arduinos. The arduino is single threaded.

`analogRead()` does not set the pin to be readable, but it returns the value in that pin.

Use analog `A0` instead of digital pin `0`

```
const int sensorPin = A0;      // Pin that SENSOR uses
boolean isOn = false; 
int sensorValue = 0, pinValue = 0; 

void loop() 
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(buttonState != lastbuttonState && buttonState == HIGH) {
     pushCounter++;
     lastbuttonState = buttonState;
  }
  if (pushCounter % 2 == 0){
    Serial.println("Power ON");
    isOn = true;
  } else {
    Serial.println("OFF");
    isOn = false;
  }
  if(isOn) {
    pinValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.println(pinValue);
    if(pinValue > 500) { Serial.println("Alarm triggered"); }
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: This has been good so far, but its not changing if the pinvalue goes over 500 to say alarm triggered, unless i switch it off then switch it back on while covering the sensor?

Comment: Sorry, but what isn't changing?

Comment: In the serial monitor, where it shows me results like 'on' when i press the button, then the current 'pinvalue', it does not update and tell me alarm triggered if I was to cover the sensor to make it go over 500. It will only do this if i switch it on while covering it?

Comment: @HJagger95 you seem to be using wrong pin for analog. use `A0`. See the answer

Comment: Right okay I see what you meant and I have changed it but now I get no result from the LDR it just says 0 in the serial monitor

Comment: I changed it back to just 0 because I wasn't getting any results with it at a0

Comment: The code in this answer puts the test `pinValue>500` inside the `buttonState!=lastbuttonState` check, so it only runs when the button is pressed. You have to put it somewhere outside of the `if`. You could define a global variable `powerOn`, set it to `true` where you write `Power ON`, and further down check the alarm inside some `if(powerOn)` block.

Comment: I have just tried this and all the serial monitor does now is spam OFF, I have tried switching around some parts to get it to work but all i got was it to stop spamming OFF and say it once then not do anything when i click the button.

Comment: Many thanks I was able to combine my old code with some of your code and suggestions to make it work!